# LaTeX Error: File `babeltools.sty' not found

Tags: miktex, babel

I am a beginner in Latex and I am trying to create a pdf using a template. I use MikTex on Windows 10. Initially I got the compilation error as shown below:

```
......\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty)
(C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xpatch\xpatch.sty
(C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
)

! LaTeX Error: File `babeltools.sty' not found.
```

After googling I found the packages for babeltools ad put the whole babeltools folder in the below location.

```
AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex
```

But the error still persists. Kindly help.

Comment: babeltools.sty is obsolete, so you should better update your template.

Comment: Further to @UlrikeFischer's comment, it's better to start with a blank document and include packages when you need them. Starting with someone else's template often complicates matters unnecessarily and sometimes (as in this case) loads obsolete packages, setting you up for trouble.

Comment: Did you `refresh file name database` (from miktex console) afterwards?